# Hamming cube has two minimal cuts $S_1, S_2$ such that $E = S_1 \cup S_2$

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the d-dimensional Hamming cube $H_d$.

Show: There are two minimal cuts $S_1, S_2$ of $H_d$ such that $E = S_1 \cup S_2$.

Hint: Consider the case where $d=2$ and construct two minimal cuts for $H_3$. Then generalize the construction for all $d \ge 2$.

Thanks for your ideas/thoughts..

Comment: Have you tried to do what the hint tells you to do? How did that go?

Comment: thanks...yes, I will shortly explain my try..I already have difficulties to understand what is even going on here...I usually do my best before asking..I'll edit my question then if I had any understanding...sorry for not being very creative this time so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of something to try.

Consider the following two cuts (red and blue) of $H_2$:

[image]

Each cut divides the cube into two equal pieces, that are symmetric if you swap all the $0$s with $1$s and vice-versa. This is easy to work with, so we try generalise this to cuts of $H_d$. We note that $H_{d+1}$ is the cartesian product $H_{d+1}= H_d \times K_2$, so we get $H_{d+1}$ by taking two copies of $H_d$ and joining the corresponding vertices with edges.

So to get $H_3$ with the right cuts, take two copies of $H_2$ (call them copy $0$ and copy $1$), reflect copy $1$ about the $y$-axis for ease of display, and swap the colours of the cuts in copy $1$:

[image]

Now you want to assign the edges between copy $0$ and copy $1$ to the two cuts in a way that gives you one big pair of cuts, that are again symmetric. This is easy enough, pick a  vertex $u$ in copy $0$ of $H_2$, and colour the edge $\{0u, 1u\}$ red. Then for every neighbour $v$ of $u$, colour the edge $\{0v, 1v\}$ blue, and so on, until all the in-between edges are coloured (such that no neighbours in a copy of $H_2$ have the same colour edge going between the two copies).

[image]

This procedure scales. So if you have these two minimal, symmetric cuts $S_1$ (red) and $S_2$ (blue) in $H_d$, you can get two minimal symmetric cuts for $H_{d+1}$ by taking the two copies of $H_d$, swapping the cuts in one, and giving the edges between the two copies 'alternating' colours. To see that this works in general, it helps a lot to notice that $H_d$ is bipartite.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive reply! :) I will soon have a serious look at it...

Comment: Yes I think this is really fine...thanks again! Maybe it is also possible to formulate it speaking about vertices...I will try it out as an alternative answer so maybe the community will tell me whether or not that is also ok...

Answer (score 0):

Every Hammingcube $H_d$ is obviously consisting in two Hammingcubes $H_{d-1}$ (copies, as it were), where the copied vertices are connected by an edge...

A cut is by definition given, when the set of vertices can be partitioned in two sets in such a way that the edges lie in between the two sets.

So, suppose one can partition a given d-dimensional Hammingcube in the described fashion. Then appearently one can construct a $d+1$-dimensional Hammingcube $H_{d+1}$ like so:

1. copy $H_d = H_d'$
2. invert the vertex colouring in $H_d'$
3. connect every vertex in $H_d$ to its copy in $H_d'$ by an edge